# WildFly with client certifactes: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca

Tags: certificate, jboss, self-signed-certificate, wildfly8, keytool

I'm trying to install a wildfly9 server with client certificate authorization. To do that I have:

1. On the Client: Create a self signed certificate:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -keystore client.keystore -validity 3650 
       -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -storetype pkcs12 -alias myClient
   ```
2. On the Client: export certificate

   ```
   keytool -exportcert -keystore client.keystore -alias myClient 
       -storetype pkcs12 -file myClient.crt
   ```
3. On the server: Import the crt certificate file into the truststore

   ```
   keytool -import -file myClient.crt   
        -keystore /etc/pki/wildfly/client.truststore
   ```
4. On the server: adjusting the wildfly config (enabling client certifacte authentication):

   ```
   <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
     <server-identities>
       <ssl>
         <keystore path="/etc/pki/wildfly/server.keystore" keystore-password="123456" alias="server" key-password="123456"/>
       </ssl>
     </server-identities>
     <authentication>
       <truststore path="/etc/pki/wildfly/client.truststore" keystore-password="123456"/>
       <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
       <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
     </authentication>
   </security-realm>
   ...
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
     <server name="default-server">
       <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" verify-client="REQUIRED"/>
        ...
      </server>
    </subsystem>
   ```

The client is a python script. For this client I need the certifacte and the key in PEM format. To export the certificate in PEM I do (all on client side):

5. Export certificate key:

   ```
   keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore client.keystore 
       -srcalias myClient -destkeystore myClient.key.tmp.pem 
       -deststoretype PKCS12 -destkeypass 123456
   ```
6. Remove the password from key (yes, of course I will also restrict the access to the key later by changing the file mode):

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -in myClient.key.tmp.pem -nocerts 
       -nodes > myClient.key.pem
   ```

   7. Remove all outside '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' and '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----' of the myClient.key.pem
   8. Export the certificat as PEM:

      keytool -exportcert -keystore client.keystore -alias myClient 
          -rfc -file myClient.pem

But every time if I want connect the server I get (on the server) the error:

```
2016-10-31 09:50:55,102 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.io] (default I/O-1) Error reading request: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslConduitEngine.engineUnwrap(JsseSslConduitEngine.java:688)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslConduitEngine.unwrap(JsseSslConduitEngine.java:620)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslConduitEngine.unwrap(JsseSslConduitEngine.java:574)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslStreamSourceConduit.read(JsseSslStreamSourceConduit.java:89)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:150)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:128)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:56)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539)
```

If I disable the client certificate authentification all is fine. so there must be anything wrong with the client certificate authentification.

Anybody knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot resolve this problem. We have another installation (our test system) which we could configure successful. However. Now we have put in front of the wildfly server a apache httpd proxy. The apache proxy is now also managing the client certificate stuff. That's works for us.